# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource on XML Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest

From reading online I've sort of gathered that what I am attempting to do may not be possible, however, I thought I'd try my luck and see if anyone here can help me with my issue.

I am attempting to get XML data from an opendata website for train information in my area. 
https://www.opendatani.gov.uk/dataset/real-time-rail-stations-arrivals-and-departures

The fact the website is all about opendata led me to believe I could easily extract this data. I was wrong!

From the link above you can see a link to see an example XML response. The name of the file is the Station index.

https://apis.opendatani.gov.uk/translink/3042A7.xml

Now, if I post the link above into postman, I get the desired data but if I do an AJAX request I get the following error.

`Failed to load https://apis.opendatani.gov.uk/translink/3042A7.xml: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Below is my ajax request, I know it's probably a long shot but if I am missing something any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://apis.opendatani.gov.uk/translink/3042A7.xml",
    ContentType: 'application/xml',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: If there isn't a CORS enabled endpoint then use a proxy on server you control or third party service

Answer (score 0):

AJAX Requests are only possible if port, protocol and domain of sender and receiver are equal. If not, the ajax call might lead to CORS.

CORS stands for Cross-origin resource sharing and has to be supported on the server side.

You can get this document and its data from your server and do what you want (even access to  that document with an ajax call once it's in your domain), however you can not access to it from another domain with an ajax call or an iframe if they don't allow this. 
Well, there are some web browser extensions to enable and disable this but you can not ask everyone to install and use them.